# Is it possible to put multiple data types into a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing and writing an Object List into a JSON file with this C# code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(drawList);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\my\sample\path\package.json", json);
```

Is it possible to also write an integer into this json file, and if so how should it be parsed so that the list and integer are separate?

Comment: why not make an object to wrap each one?

Comment: Would that look like what Fran has in the code below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {integer = 1, list = drawList});
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\my\sample\path\package.json", json);
```

Comment: Ahh..thanks. I'm pretty new to json so I don't really know much about how it works. Do you know if I could turn that into separate javascript objects when I read the json file in my JS script?

Comment: It will work just like c#.  You can parse the json back to a object, then read the properties off the root object

Comment: How would you deserialize this ?